# Rails User has_many posts, has_many favorite_posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

first of all sorry for English

So i already have "user - posts" one to many association, which means that each post can have just ONE author, and now i want to add "favorite posts" button to user profile, and "add to favorite" button to each post, so the question is how to implement this correct way? should i rework my user - post association?
or create some another model? I,m a bit confused. Thank in advance !

**Actually i want this result :**

**@user.posts** #return all posts created by this user

**@user.favorite_posts**  #return posts added to favorites by this user

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..20}

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ratings
  enum role: [ :user, :admin ]

  def calculate_average
    ratings.blank? ? 0 : ratings.map(&:value).inject(:+) / ratings.count.to_f
  end
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**EDIT**

**Alright look how i've done this, it works exactly the way I wanted it.**

**Here is my user model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..20}

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorite_posts, through: :favorites, source: "post"
  enum role: [ :user, :admin ]

  def calculate_average
    ratings.blank? ? 0 : ratings.map(&:value).inject(:+) / ratings.count.to_f
  end
end
```

Comment: i'm new to programming and i've read rails guide about associations, but i can't understand how to use it in my case, i mean that each user has many posts created by him and he also has many posts that he marked as favorite but these favorite posts shouldn't nessesary belong to this user.

Comment: I wrote what i want above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`many-to-many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationships for the favorite post, at first run this command to create a table `favorite_posts`

```
rails g model FavoritePost user:references post:references
```

Then

```
rails db:migrate
```

Then add these to your model would look like this:

```
#=> model/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :favorite_posts, dependent: :destroy # or you can use only this line except second if you will face any problem
    has_many :posts, through: :favorite_posts
end

#=> model/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :favorite_posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :favorite_posts
end

#=> model/favorite_post.rb
class FavoritePost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

That was relation part, now create a favorite post part. For the fresh code you can create a controller, i.e.

```
rails g controller favorites
```

Then your routes file:

```
resources :favorites
```

An example of the new routes using `rake routes`:

```
    favorites GET    /favorites(.:format)          favorites#index
              POST   /favorites(.:format)          favorites#create
 new_favorite GET    /favorites/new(.:format)      favorites#new
edit_favorite GET    /favorites/:id/edit(.:format) favorites#edit
     favorite GET    /favorites/:id(.:format)      favorites#show
              PATCH  /favorites/:id(.:format)      favorites#update
              PUT    /favorites/:id(.:format)      favorites#update
              DELETE /favorites/:id(.:format)      favorites#destroy
```

In your view file add something like this:

```
# For creating favorite
<%= link_to "Favorite", favorites_path(user: current_user, post: post.id), class: 'btn bf-save-btn', method: :post, data: {disable_with: "Saving..."}, title: "Add to favorite" %>

# For deleting favorite list
<%= link_to "Unfavorite", favorite_path(post.id), class: 'btn af-save-btn', method: :delete, data: {disable_with: "Removing...."}, title: "Remove from favorite" %>
```

In `favorites_controller.rb`:

```
def index
    @saves = current_user.favorite_post
end
# index.html.erb
<% @saves.each do |fav| %>
     <%= link_to fav.post.post_title, post_path(fav.post) %>
<% end %>

def create
    @save = FavoritePost.new(post_id: params[:post], user: current_user)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @save.save
            flash[:success] = 'Saved'
            format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @save, :status => :created, :location => @save }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @save.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def destroy
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @save = FavoritePost.where(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: post.id).first

    respond_to do |format|
        if @save.destroy
            flash[:error] = 'Unsaved'
            format.html { redirect_to request.referer, status: 303  }
            format.js { redirect_to request.referer, status: 303  }
            # format.xml  { head :ok }
        end
    end
end
```

That's it for favorite / unfavorite functionality. Now you need to create some logic for when to show `Favorite` and when `Unfavorite`.

For this requirements has many ways, at first you need to understand this then you can whatever you want.

Also, to achieve this without reloading your page you can try some `Ajax`.

**Update**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    mount_uploader :avatar, ImageUploader
    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..20}

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :ratings

    # Newly added
    has_many :favorite_posts, dependent: :destroy # or you can use only this line except second if you will face any problem
    has_many :posts, through: :favorite_posts

    enum role: [ :user, :admin ]

    def calculate_average
        ratings.blank? ? 0 : ratings.map(&:value).inject(:+) / ratings.count.to_f
    end
end
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this

Comment: Okay, but now i can't type @post.user.username in my post view to display the post author right ?

Comment: Could perhaps rename the `Post` model's `has_many :users` association to something like `has_many :favoriting_users` (or something?) @fool-dev, to make this a little clearer for Kizlo?

Comment: thank you for explanation, but i still don't understand how should i now 
display author username in my post view, cause what i have now is like
<%= @post.user.username %> 
but in your code post has_MANY users

Comment: @Kizlokizlo, look your model take the same which was before, newly just added two line like `has_many :favorite_posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :favorite_posts` you don't need to edit anything, just add these two lines

Comment: @Kizlokizlo, See the **Update** section on my answer

Comment: What does `user.posts` mean now? You have it twice in the model. One for posts created by the user (`has_many :posts`) and one for posts liked by the user (`has_many :posts, through: :favorite_posts`)

Comment: @Pablo, it will be `user.favorite_posts` for only which post are favorites

Comment: For showing post title it will be `obj.post.post_title` after fetching `current_user.favorite_posts` see the `favorites_controller.rb` from answer @Pablo

Answer (score 1):

Create a new model for 'UserFavoritePost' stored post_id and user_id. And create a custom association for favorite_posts

```
class UserFavoritePost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post    
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_favorite_posts
  has_many :favorite_posts, throught: :user_favorite_posts, class: 'Post'

end
```

Comment: This is incomplete, no? Also, what does it add that @fool-dev's already submitted answer doesn't cover?

Comment: @fool-dev's answer returns for user.favorite_posts doesn't return actual posts records. That return post_id and user_id.

Comment: Um, yes, it does.

Comment: user's favorite_posts should return favorite post records or favorite post_ids?

Comment: Okay it seems like exactly what i need, thank you i'll try this

Comment: it should return records

Comment: Which @fool-dev's original answer does. This is just a copy, and an incomplete one at that.

Answer (score 1):

fool-dev's answer does not provide a direct access to favorite posts, so the index view requires a loop. Prasanna's approach solves this, but his answer has been unfairly accused of incomplete and plagiarism :-). So here is the complete approach:

You need a **many to many** relationship, that´s true, so you need a join model and table. But this model is auxiliary. No important logic should be there, and I don´t think it deserves a controller or views.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy # Posts created by this user
  has_many :favs, dependent: :destroy  
  has_many :fav_posts, through: :favs # Favorite posts for this user
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fav_users, through: :favs # Users who have this post as favorite
end

class Fav < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This allows to access all posts created by the user and all his favorite posts using two different methods in the user class.

```
@posts = current_user.posts         # Posts created by this user
@fav_posts = current_user.fav_posts # Favorite posts
```

In the view:

```
<h1><% current_user.name %></h1>
<h2>Your posts</h2>
<%= render @posts %>
<h2>Your favorite posts from other users</h2>
<%= render @fav_posts %>
```

You don't need a controller to create, view or delete favorite posts. Just handle this logic in the User or Post controllers. For example, to favorite or unfavorite a post just add fav and unfav methods in the PostsController.

```
def fav
  current_user.fav_posts << Post.find(params[:id])
end

def unfav
  current_user.favs_posts.destroy(Post.find(params[:id]))
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= link_to "Favorite", fav_post_path(id: post.id) %>
<%= link_to "Unfavorite", unfav_post_path(id: post.id) %>
```

You should add these methods in your routes:

```
post '/posts/:id/fav', to: 'posts#fav', as: 'fav_post'    
post '/posts/:id/unfav', to: 'posts#unfav', as: 'unfav_post'
```